# Query for post and costom post_type in same category filtered by meta for post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I need to search post and custom post type which are both in the same category, but I need to filter only post type by a meta with a custom field. 
Using meta_query I tried

```
$meta_query =   array(array(
      'key'      => 'public',
      'value' => '1',
      'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
      'compare' => '='    
    )
);
```

but simple post doesn't have this meta so they are excluded. 
How can I refer this meta query only to custom post type and not to post?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. 
I needed to change meta_query this way:

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'   => 'public',
        'value' => '1',
    ), 
    array(
        'key'     => 'public',
        'value'   => '',  // necessary to work!!!
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    ), 
);
```

1st array search for post with meta key 'public' set to 1

2nd array add post without meta key 'public'

note that in 2nd array it's necessary to add value also if useless!